# Android custom view with canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I would like to create a custom bullet points in android using canvas.

Following is my code.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            int x = getWidth();
            int y = getHeight();
            int radius;
            radius = 100;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
            canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);
        }
```

But it doesn't produce the view that Im trying to get. Im enclosing a image as a reference. I wish to get such view.

[image]

Comment: Hey there could you be a bit more precise about your problem ? Don't you get any result or do you just want to get another one ? And please provide a snippet of how you implement your custom view...

Comment: i dont get the result that i would like to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is going wrong in this case is you getting width and height to draw your circle in the center, please try to get your width and height of you parent view like this:

```
@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
   int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
   int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
   this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth/2, parentHeight);
   this.setLayoutParams(new *ParentLayoutType*.LayoutParams(parentWidth/2,parentHeight));
}
```

And take these values for alignment of your circle,
let me know if this was your problem.

Comment: why `setMeasuredDimension` **and** `setLayoutParams` **and** `super.onMeasure` ? are you sure what you are doing?